# How to schedule currency_rates_update cronjob weekly on specified day of week?

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, configuration, cron, currency-rates

I'm trying to schedule *currency_rates_update* (webservicex) cronjob weekly but the Magento interface not give me the possibility to select the day so I should change it by database (otherwise the system set to 1, monday).

Any solution or patch to solve this issue?

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression is saved by the config backend model `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Currency_Cron`

#### Relevant code:

```
    $cronExprArray = array(
        intval($time[1]),                                   # Minute
        intval($time[0]),                                   # Hour
        ($frequency == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Month
        '*',                                                # Month of the Year
        ($frequency == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',        # Day of the Week
    );
```

A quick and dirty solution would be to override this class and replace `'1'` with your desired weekday.

A clean solution would be to create an own backend model and replace it for this one configuration in a custom `system.xml`:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <currency>
            <groups>
                <import>
                    <fields>
                        <service>
                             <backend_model>your_module/system_config_backend_currency_cron</backend_model>
                        </service>
                    </fields>
                </import>
            </groups>
        </currency>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Then you can also add another select box for the weekday and use this in your customized backend model instead of the hardcoded `'1'`

Comment: A dirtier solution is to set the field 'crontab/jobs/currency_rates_update/schedule/cron_expr' in the 'core_config_data' table with the desired value taking attention to avoid to update in the backend.

Comment: i got error in currency update cron job in magento 2.2.2. (See this screenshot) :  https://www.screencast.com/t/Ouu1wCTz8